# Who are the key developers, and where can I follow their progress and decision making?

Tags: development, news-coverage, testnet, multi-signature

I want to follow the most up to date developments of Bitcoin, (such as M of N transaction confirmation).

Who are the primary developers of Bitcoin and what is the most efficient way to track the progress of this and similar activities?

I'm interested in reading either a detailed activity view, or a high level bullet point of key developments.  Ideally someone would offer both information formats as an answer.

---

A nice summary view would include the following ideas and a status on testnet and on the production network:

- [IPv6 support](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=81378.0)
- [Zero confirmation AKA miner promise](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2831/1878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core developers are listed on [the main Bitcoin page](http://bitcoin.org/), while everyone that contributed code are listed on the [About page](http://bitcoin.org/about.html). Probably the most up-to-date info on what is happening with the code would be on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

Comment: Discussion on activities can be found on [SourceForge mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=bitcoin-development).

Comment: And the #bitcoin-dev IRC channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 0):

The progress is being tracked through the "[Bitcoin Improvement Proposal](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Improvement_Proposals)".  There is a grid of several new features that may or may not make it into a future version of the client.

[Learn about the BIP submission process here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0001)

Comment: Improvements local to the reference client (or any client) that don't influence others will typically not be turned into BIPs.